# Using GWT to create distributable libraries

Tags: gwt, migration

I am hoping that someone might be able to tell me how I could use GWT to create a javascript library which I can easily distribute for use in other plain old javascript applications.

The reasoning for this is that we have a very very complex web application, and are looking to eventually move it to GWT to help manage the complexity and reduce the learning curve for new developers. However, I would like to be able to replace the application from the bottom up, that is, start moving some of our core libraries into native GWT, and worry about the UI last. So I need to have our existing applications be able to reference and use the compiled GWT that replaces the existing code.

I realize that this might not be possible given how GWT compiles, but if it is, that would be amazing. It would also help in the future when we need to expose a javascript API to our GWT application.

Thanks,

Casey

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because of the way GWT declares its namespaces in Javascript you can't just use straight  GWT in normal Javascript or at least it's not that easy.
However you can check out the [gwt-exporter](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-exporter/) project which might be of some use.